# Memcached gem issue with passenger getting MemcachedClientError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, passenger

I have recently migrated my code from Rails 2.3.4 to rails 3 and started using passenger with it. I am also using memcached gem and i randomly see  Memcached::ClientError and Memcached::ServerIsMarkedDead. I have read this article which says passenger smart spawning has issues with memcache socket based connect. So i tried the fix mention on their site

```
CACHE = MemCache.new memcache_options
CACHE.servers = '127.0.0.1:11211'
begin
   PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
     if forked
       # We're in smart spawning mode, so...
       # Close duplicated memcached connections - they will open themselves
       CACHE.reset
     end
   end
# In case you're not running under Passenger (i.e. devmode with mongrel)
rescue NameError => error
end
```

But still i get the same error. has it got something to do with the memcached library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a Rails 3.1.3 app on Ubuntu with memcached, I am using the Dalli gem to interface with it, not a single glitch so far. You might want to look into that.
[Dalli Gem on GitHub](https://github.com/mperham/dalli)